# Generate a path appending query string in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there any facility to generate a path for a given route and arguments, **appending the query string automatically**? As a temporary workaround i'm using a self made macro:

```
{% macro path(route, args, with_query) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set with_query = with_query|default(false) and app.request.queryString %}
    {{ path(route, args) ~ (with_query ? '?' ~ app.request.queryString : '' ) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Is there some native function in Symfony2/Twig for doing this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A nice thing with **path** Twig extension is that unknow parameters passed through the args array are automatically appended at the end of the URL as GET paramaters :

```
{{ path('route_id', {'routeParam':'foo', 'unknownParam':'bar'}) }}
```

will produce

> /path/to/route/foo?unknownParam=bar

Comment: Well, answer accepted, even if i need it more dynamic (i.e. unknownParam are more and not fixed).

Comment: this is just a sample, you can put a variable for ''unknownParam'' and ''bar'' !

Comment: This 'unknown parameters' functionality is part of the core Symfony2 router - so you can use the same approach in your controllers. From the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings): $router->generate('blog', array('page' => 2, 'category' => 'Symfony')); // /blog/2?category=Symfony

Comment: The parenthesis is slightly wrong. Should be:
`{{ path('route_id', {'routeParam':'foo', 'unknownParam':'bar'}) }}`

Comment: Is there a possibility to produce `/path/to/route/foo?unknownParam` (without `=` sign)? I tried `{{ path('route_id', {'routeParam':'foo', 'unknownParam':''}) }}` but it generates `/path/to/route/foo?unknownParam=`

Comment: I don't think so, this is not the proper way to use GET params.

Answer (score 5):

As simple as :

```
{{ path('route_id', app.request.query.all) }}
```